# How to set multiple keys in sorted function python

Tags: python

```
19070986    fName1  lName1  5213
18764992    fName1  lName1  31211
81089820    fName1  lName1  223231
```

I have this tab separated file and I am trying to sort by last field and this is my code:

```
import csv

import operator
sample = open('filename.csv','r')
csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter='\t')
sort = sorted(csv1,key = operator.itemgetter(3))

for eachline in sort:
    print eachline
```

But the output that I get is the sequence 223231->31211->5213.
So if I use float as a key.How can I set multiple keys?

Comment: `key` can be any callable that takes an item from the sequence and returns something to sort it by, e.g. `key=lambda row: float(row[3])`

Comment: can you show the equivalent code for the aforementioned method using operator.itemgetter(3).

Comment: I echo jonrsharpe's sentiment that it's not particularly desirable, but perhaps looking at what it looks like will be useful.  It's either `key=lambda row: float(operator.itemgetter(3)(row))`, or you write a custom `combine` function that takes functions `f(x)` and `g(x)` and return function `f(g(x))`, then `key=combine(int, operator.itemgetter(3))`.  But unless you're going to do a lot of this, just using `lambda x:int(x[3])` is much easier.

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple keys? It seems that you only want to use the fourth column as a float instead of a string.